# Change TRIM to TRIM(substitute) - macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which trims the unnecessary spaces in all rows. However, instead of standard trim I would like to use Trim(substitute) function - as sometimes standard trim function doesn't work for me. The difference between Trim and trim(substitute) is

**TRIM:**

=TRIM(A2)

**TRIM(SUBSTITUTE):**

=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A4,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))

I tried to change the code in the trim line to:

```
MyCell.Value = Trim(SUBSTITUTE(MyCell.Value,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))
```

but unfortunately it doesn't. Could anyone please help me to adjust the code to make it work?

**MY TRIM MACRO**

```
Sub GOOD_CT_TrimBText()
Cells.Select
Dim MyCell As Range
On Error Resume Next
    Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
    For Each MyCell In Selection.Cells
        MyCell.Value = Trim(MyCell.Value)
    Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE` is a worksheet function.  To use it in VBA, you need to reference it as `Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute`.  `TRIM` is also a worksheet function.  However, there is also a VBA function named `Trim` that that does the same thing, which is why you can call it directly in VBA.  `Replace` is the VBA equivalent of `SUBSTITUTE`.

Comment: Oh... thank you Brian for clarification. Indeed, the new MiVoth's code works. I don't want to spam here, so I would like to say here thank you to MiVoth for the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know, for what reason you want to use `SUBSTITUTE`. If you want to erase all spaces in a string, then you can try this:

```
MyCell.Value = Replace(MyCell.Value, " ", vbNullString)
```

(On a side note: don't use "Select". It just slows down the macro and is unnecessary most of the times)

Edit: Now i know, what you mean. As said by @KazJaw you can alter it to:

```
MyCell.Value = Trim(Replace(MyCell.Value, Chr(160), Chr(32)))
```

I've tested it and it worked.

Comment: Replace doesn't work for me as it deletes ALL spaces (also those ones in the middle). And Trim(substitute) is the solution to by pass the annoying Excel manner (some of the data when it is copied from the websites has the formatting that prevents to either use Trim or Replace). That is why I want to use Trim(substitute)

Comment: @mgunia, I think @MiVoth idea is correct but you possibly need to adjust and mix it with other functions in this way: `Trim(Replace(MyCell.Value,Chr(160),Chr(32)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(I8,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))*1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.....

```
MyCell.Value=Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyCell.Value, Chr(160), Chr(32)))
```